# Pandas - Count of tasks spanning several X minute timeslots

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following data:

```
Index   Task        Start                       Finish
0       RandomName  2018-10-15T13:30:00+00:00   2018-10-15T13:41:00+00:00
1       RandomName  2018-10-15T13:40:00+00:00   2018-10-15T13:51:00+00:00
2       RandomName  2018-10-15T13:50:00+00:00   2018-10-15T13:51:00+00:00
3       RandomName  2018-10-15T14:10:00+00:00   2018-10-15T14:11:00+00:00
4       RandomName  2018-10-15T14:20:00+00:00   2018-10-15T14:21:00+00:00
5       RandomName  2018-10-15T14:30:00+00:00   2018-10-15T14:31:00+00:00
```

What I am trying to do is to generate 5 minute segments (kind of timeslots) of this dataframe and count how many occurrences of these tasks are taking place in said segment and try to visualize it. Since these tasks have duration, I first had to generate the segments by the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def main():

   input_file = "input.csv"    
   df = pd.read_csv(
                input_file
                ,parse_dates=['Start','Finish']
                ,names=['Index', 'Job', 'Start', 'Finish']
                ,index_col='Index'
                ,header=None
                )

    # Find the duration of each task.
    df['Start']  = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'],dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
    df['Finish'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Finish'],dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
    df.loc[:,'Duration'] = df['Finish'].dt.minute - df['Start'].dt.minute

    # Define the range and split it into 5 minute segments
    rng_min = df['Start'].min()  # Earliest Date
    rng_max = df['Finish'].max() # Latest Date
    current = rng_min
    while current < rng_max:
         current += timedelta(minutes=5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

A task can extend to several 5 minute segments so it is not exactly a simple count. I'm completely stuck as what to do from this point on so any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

*Edit - Adding more information:*

The tasks are irrelevant as the goal here is to produce the empty (available) 5 minute segments

Edit 2 - Adding what it should look like:

```
 Timeslot   Start Time           End Time          Tasks Running
  1         10/15/18 13:30  10/15/18 13:35  1
  2         10/15/18 13:35  10/15/18 13:40  1
  3         10/15/18 13:40  10/15/18 13:45  2
  4         10/15/18 13:45  10/15/18 13:50  3
```

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: Added on post  - thank you!

Comment: it can de done as follows:
(a) create a dictionary with keys as start time, start time +5 , start time +10minutes    till you cover the last record start time.
(b) compare the finish time of each task with each of the key. if it is greater 
    than the key value  append it as list value. so you will be having {'start_window1':['T1','T2'],   'start_window2':['T1','T2'] ...} and so on where T1,T2 are task names
(c) count the length of each list corresponding to the key so get the answer    
    what you require,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) followed by [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) on the time series index to do what you want:

Resample allows you to change the frequency of a datetime index. In this case, you want to 'upsample' - increase the number of steps in your data
Reindex then lets you fill in gaps with NAs

---

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import math


def main(input_file="untitled.txt", minutes_per_segment=5):

    df = pd.read_csv(input_file
                     ,parse_dates=['Start','Finish']
                     ,names=['Index', 'Task', 'Start', 'Finish']
                     ,index_col='Index'
                     ,header=0
                     )

    # Find the duration of each task.
    df['Start']  = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
    df['Finish'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Finish'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')

    # Get the number of <segments> minute segments that the task 
    # runs for, rounded up to the next integer value
    df['Segments'] = (df.apply(lambda x: math.ceil((x.Finish - 
                                                x.Start).total_seconds()/60/minutes_per_segment), 
                               axis='columns'))

    # You can skip this step if the values in your Task_Name are unique
    # if not, you need something so you can treat each entry independently
    df['Task_ID'] = df.index.astype(str)
    df['Task_Name'] = df.apply(lambda x: '_'.join([x.Task, x.Task_ID]), axis=1)

    # create a new df so that the start and end times are in separate rows
    df2 = pd.concat([df[['Task_Name','Start', 'Segments']]
                         .rename(columns={'Start':'Time'}), 
                     df[['Task_Name','Finish', 'Segments']]
                         .rename(columns={'Finish':'Time'})])

    df2 = df2.sort_values(by='Task_Name').set_index('Time')
    df2.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df2.index)

    # group by the task name 
    # resample to create 5-minute blocks 
    # clean up columns
    df3 = (df2.groupby('Task_Name')
              .apply(lambda x: x.resample(rule='{interval}T'.format(interval=minutes_per_segment), 
                                          label='right',
                                          closed='right')
                                .asfreq()
                                .ffill()
                    ) 
              .reset_index(level=1)
              .rename(columns={'level_1':'Time'})
              .reset_index(drop=True)) 

    # reset the index as a datetime Index - needed to do the next reindex step 
    df3.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
    df3.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3.index)


    # group by the time and aggregate the data:
    #     count the number of tasks in the time group
    #     (optional) create a list of the task names (you can comment out this line, and the name in the 'reorder' step at the bottom, if you don't need this) 
    # reindex to get all the 5-minute segments in the date range
    df4 = (df3.reset_index()
              .groupby('Time')
              .agg({'Task_Name': {'Tasks_Running': 'count', 
                                  'Task_Names': lambda x: list(x) # you can get rid of this line if you prefer
                                 }
                   })
              .reindex(pd.date_range(start=df3.index.min(), 
                                     end=df3.index.max(), 
                                     freq='{segments}min'.format(segments=minutes_per_segment)))
          )

    # remove the multi-index created in the agg step
    df4.columns = [name[1] for name in df4.columns]
    df4.index.name = 'Start_Time'
    df4.reset_index(inplace=True)

    # Fill in the missing task count (any time periods newly added by the reindex will have 0 tasks)
    df4.Tasks_Running.fillna(0, inplace=True)

    # get the end time from the start time column
    df4['End_Time'] = df4.Start_Time.shift(-1).ffill()

    # reorder the columns for ease of reading
    df4 = df4[['Start_Time','End_Time','Tasks_Running', 'Task_Names']] # comment this out if you commented out the line in the df4 agg 

    df4.index.name = 'Timeslot'
    df4.reset_index(inplace=True)

    return df4

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

This gives you:

```
    Timeslot          Start_Time            End_Time  Tasks_Running                    Task_Names 
0          0 2018-10-15 13:30:00 2018-10-15 13:35:00            1.0                 [RandomName0] 
1          1 2018-10-15 13:35:00 2018-10-15 13:40:00            1.0                 [RandomName0] 
2          2 2018-10-15 13:40:00 2018-10-15 13:45:00            2.0    [RandomName0, RandomName1] 
3          3 2018-10-15 13:45:00 2018-10-15 13:50:00            2.0    [RandomName0, RandomName1] 
4          4 2018-10-15 13:50:00 2018-10-15 13:55:00            2.0    [RandomName1, RandomName2] 
5          5 2018-10-15 13:55:00 2018-10-15 14:00:00            2.0    [RandomName1, RandomName2] 
6          6 2018-10-15 14:00:00 2018-10-15 14:05:00            0.0                           NaN 
7          7 2018-10-15 14:05:00 2018-10-15 14:10:00            0.0                           NaN 
8          8 2018-10-15 14:10:00 2018-10-15 14:15:00            1.0                 [RandomName3] 
9          9 2018-10-15 14:15:00 2018-10-15 14:20:00            1.0                 [RandomName3] 
10        10 2018-10-15 14:20:00 2018-10-15 14:25:00            1.0                 [RandomName4] 
11        11 2018-10-15 14:25:00 2018-10-15 14:30:00            1.0                 [RandomName4] 
12        12 2018-10-15 14:30:00 2018-10-15 14:35:00            1.0                 [RandomName5] 
13        13 2018-10-15 14:35:00 2018-10-15 14:35:00            1.0                 [RandomName5]
```

Comment: Hi Katelie, thank you! I tried your code but there is one bug: the segment duration is changing from 5 to 10 minutes (its in your reply example as well).

Comment: my apologies - you need use `resample`, followed by `reindex`, to create all the 5-minute intervals. I've edited my answer to correct it.

Comment: Thank you Katelie,you have no idea how much appreciated is your help! Unfortunately I still run into errors upon reaching the resampling part: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis  [Line 40]  which is ` .apply(lambda x: x.resample(rule='{interval}T'.format(interval=minutes_per_segment), 
                                          label='right',
                                          closed='right')` . Could you please help me with that? Is it because the task_name is not unique?

Comment: hmm... Do you have any rows where the start time is the same as the end time (especially in minutes)? It works for me with combinations of non-unique task names and straight up duplicated rows, but not where end time = start time. If you need to consider sub-second times, it's possible you might need to change the `total_seconds` bit in the timedelta calculation.

Comment: Again thank you for your time. I just run through the dataset to check for start = end times and couldn't find any. I tried using the same example data as above -  but still run into the same problem =/

Comment: try one more time on the sample data, if you're willing? I realized that the file reading had "Job" not "Task" like in the example, and the Task_Name creation got lost when I edited. I also change 'header=None' to 'header=0', to account for the column labels in the sample data (otherwise it wouldn't read for me), but this may be different in your actual data. My guess is that the column names may have been weird? That value error can be either an index or column issue.

Comment: Thank you very much - works like a charm! I actually fixed these before, but for some reason - this time it worked? God knows! Again many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try something similar to this effort:

```
#Copying your original dataframe into clipboard buffer
df = pd.read_clipboard(index_col='Index')

df[['Start', 'Finish']] = df[['Start','Finish']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df_out = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.date_range(x.Start, x.Finish, freq='5T')), axis=1)\
  .stack()\
  .value_counts(bins=pd.date_range(df.Start.min(), df.Finish.max(), freq='5T'))\
  .sort_index()

df_out.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df_out.index.to_tuples())

df_out = df_out.rename_axis(['Start', 'Finish']).rename('Task Running').reset_index()
print(df_out)

df_out.plot('Start','Task Running')
```

Output (Note: ambiguity in inclusiveness of the start or end of interval, ie should a value at 13:35 be include in the end of an interval or at the start of the next interval):

```
                           Start              Finish  Task Running
0  2018-10-15 13:29:59.999999999 2018-10-15 13:35:00             2
1  2018-10-15 13:35:00.000000000 2018-10-15 13:40:00             2
2  2018-10-15 13:40:00.000000000 2018-10-15 13:45:00             1
3  2018-10-15 13:45:00.000000000 2018-10-15 13:50:00             2
4  2018-10-15 13:50:00.000000000 2018-10-15 13:55:00             0
5  2018-10-15 13:55:00.000000000 2018-10-15 14:00:00             0
6  2018-10-15 14:00:00.000000000 2018-10-15 14:05:00             0
7  2018-10-15 14:05:00.000000000 2018-10-15 14:10:00             1
8  2018-10-15 14:10:00.000000000 2018-10-15 14:15:00             0
9  2018-10-15 14:15:00.000000000 2018-10-15 14:20:00             1
10 2018-10-15 14:20:00.000000000 2018-10-15 14:25:00             0
11 2018-10-15 14:25:00.000000000 2018-10-15 14:30:00             1
```

Visualized Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html?highlight=groupby) is a useful method of segmenting data. Use the date_range function to assign the segment times to a column, using a frequency of 5 mins. Expand this column to create a new dataframe using itertuples(), which iterates through each row of the dataframe. From here you can run groupby functions on the data, or change it how you want.

```
    df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
    df['Finish'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Finish'])
    df['Segments'] = df.index.map(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=df['Start'][x], end=df['Finish'][x], freq='5Min'))
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([(d, t.Task) for t in df.itertuples() for d in t.Segments])
    df1 = df1.rename(columns={0:'Time', 1:'Task'})
    grouped = df1.groupby(['Time'])
    for time, group in grouped:
        print(group)
```